# How do I clear positional arguments in my function(s) in Python?

Tags: python, input, arguments, output

There was a looping error with add, but now that I can add data to my txt file, there is this error using 'see' to list my data. Below is the erro:

TypeError:list_champs() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given.

I cannot see where I added a parameter unknowingly that doesn't need one in my current code.

```
# file = open("champs.txt", "w+")

FILENAME = "champs.txt"

def write_champs(champs):
    with open(FILENAME, "w") as file:
        for champ in champs:
            file.write(champ + "\n")

def read_champs():
    champs = []
    with open(FILENAME) as file:
        for line in file:
            line = line.replace("\n", "")
            champs.append(line)
    return champs

def list_champs():
    for i in range(len(champs)):
        champ = champs[i]
        print(str(i+1) + " - " + champs)
    print()

def add_champ(champs):
    champ = input("Champion: ")
    #year = input("Season:    ")
    #champ = []
    champs.append(champ)
    #champ.append(year)
    write_champs(champs)
    print(champ + " was added.\n")

def display_menu():
    print("Premier League Champions")
    print("++++++++++++++++++++++++")
    print("COMMANDS")
    print("see  - See the list of Champions")
    print("add  - Add a Champion to the list")
    print("exit - Exit program")
    print()

def main():
    display_menu()
    champs = read_champs()
    while True:
        command = input("Enter command: ")
        if command == "see":
            list_champs(champs)
        elif command == "add":
            add_champ(champs)
        elif command == "exit":
            print("Later!")
            break
        else:
            print("Input not valid. Try again.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

As always help is much appreciated!

Comment: Please reduce and enhance this into the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  You posted about 50 lines of code for a five-line problem.

Comment: Please include the line of code causing the problem with the error message. We are all used to python traces and posting the traceback itself is usually the best for us.

Comment: Thank you for the MRE advice. I fixed the problem prior to using MRE on the code that wasn't working. Will keep MRE in mind for next time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your `def list_champs` to support arguments:

```py
def list_champs(champs):
    for i in range(len(champs)):
        champ = champs[i]
        print(str(i+1) + " - " + champs)
    print()
```

Comment: Removing `champs` from the function call won't work. He needs to change the function definition.

Comment: I changed 'def list_champs():' to 'def list_champs(champs)' and that fixed it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**function definition**

```
def list_champs():
```

**function call**

```
        list_champs(champs)
```

Do you want the function to take an argument, or not?
Fix one or the other, depending on your intended design.

Comment: Don't ask a question while answering one

Comment: The question is rhetorical; I've clarified.